# Caching service calls in Quarkus

Tags: java, quarkus

Does Quarkus have something like `org.springframework.cache.annotation.@Cacheable` out of the box ? (could not find any mentioning of that in the doc)

to be put on some service method,

that would keep / cache prev response for some period of time and preserve the call stack / logs.

Similar to to that Spring `@Cacheable` annotation?

Answer (score 5):

We have a `quarkus-cache` extension in Quarkus which allows to cache methods with a simple `@CacheResult` annotation.

There are several other annotations allowing to fine tune the behavior and everything is described in our Quarkus documentation: https://quarkus.io/guides/cache .

This extension is backed by Caffeine but you can also use Redis with the `quarkus-redis-cache` extension, which is described at length in https://quarkus.io/guides/cache-redis-reference .